# (С++) Не получается открыть файл

Tags: c++

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

string path = "myFile.txt";

ofstream fout;

fout.open("myFile.txt");

if (!fout.is_open()) {
    cout << "Ошибка открытия файла";
}
else {
    fout << "Это наши данные!";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << "Введите число";
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        fout << a;
        fout << "\n";
    }
}
fout.close();

return 0;
```

Comment: Можете поподробней расписать вопрос? Как понять не открывается? Какая ошибка вылетает? Или что? И да может не так название ввели файла или этого файла нет вообще.

Comment: При запуске программы в корневой папке проекта не создаётся текстовый документ, следовательно не может открыть, пробовал самостоятельно создать файл "myFile.txt", но все равно не получается.

Comment: А у меня все работает) Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014142/ofstream-cannot-open-the-file) можете почитать ответ. Может что-то из вашего есть.

Comment: *пробовал самостоятельно создать файл "myFile.txt", но все равно не получается* - а посмотреть, что именно за ошибка? Может, прав не хватает? Вы же даже операционную систему не указали - ну как воспроизвести вашу ошибку?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, ни я, ни несколько человек, написавших комментарии, не видят в Вашем коде никаких ошибок, которые могли бы приводить к такой проблеме.

Иногда в таких случаях помогает способ "переписать всё заново".

Я могу предложить переписать с использованием stream, получится довольно просто. (Просто я вижу, stream для ввода - вывода с консоли Вы пользуетесь)

Конечно, это имеет смысл делать, только если у Вас нет цели использовать именно функцию open()

Через stream можно так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

...

ifstream fin("myFile.txt");

int a;
fin >> a;
```

это если из файла нужно читать

Ну, или если в него собираетесь писать:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

...

ofstream fout("myFile.txt");

int a;
...
fout << a << endl;
```

Comment: Это ни при чем. `open` - нормальная функция-член, так что ваш ответ не более чем комментарий о вкусовых, так сказать, пристрастиях :)

Comment: @Harry - совершенно согласен с критикой. Поменяю ответ, если он бесполезен - готов его убрать.

Comment: Проблема решилась, когда зашёл с аккаунта администратора

Comment: «Когда зашел с экаунта администратора» - да, это отлично помогает!

Comment: *Проблема решилась, когда зашёл с аккаунта администратора* - pзачит, как и писали в комментариях, у вас просто не хватало прав для этого каталога...